# increase div as content in it increases

Tags: css, html, fluid-layout

I have my HTML structure like this:

```
<div id="pagewrap">

    <div id="header">
    </div>

    <div id="content">

     <div id="left"></div>
     <div id="right"></div>

     </div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

I want to increase size of content div  when either divs  in content div increases as same size as other div.

How can I achieve this?

This is how my css is:

```
  #pagewrap
    {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
    }

    #header{width: 100%;height:97px;position:relative;}

    #left{position:absolute;left:0px;width:20%;background-color:#1C2326;}

    #right{position:absolute;right:0px;width:80%;background-color:#2D3538;color:#fff;}

    #footer{clear:both;height: 80px;background-color:#72D27C;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the wrapper to be affected by the contents' dimensions, you can't use `position: absolute` in the inner divs. Try floating them instead (and add `overflow: hidden` to the container to clear the inner floats):

```css
#pagewrap { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
#content { overflow: hidden; }
#header { width: 100%; height: 97px; position:relative; }
#left { float: left; width: 20%; background-color: #1C2326; }
#right { float: left; width: 80%; background-color: #2D3538; color: #fff; }
#footer  { height: 80px; background-color: #72D27C; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h4hbx/

Comment: no size is not increasing .. it is increasing upto browser height and stopping

Comment: Do you have CSS rules on html and/or body?

Comment: See this: http://jsfiddle.net/h4hbx/3/. If you need the left column background colored to the bottom, I suggest just painting the #content div with the same color.

Comment: hmm good idea,  if i want to increase left column by keeping right constant size then what i should i do then???

Comment: You don't know which column will be the tallest?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38637/discussion-between-saikiran-and-bfavaretto)

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FxHxd/) is closer to what you had in mind. You can let the left div (static position, no float) set the height of content, and then pin the top and bottom of the right div to the content div. As left grows, content grows, and right is tied to content, giving you the effect you want. However, this is asymmetrical -- if you want either div to cause the other to follow it, that's another problem.

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#pagewrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#content {
    position: relative;
}
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height:97px;
}
#left {
    left:0px;
    width:20%;
    background-color:#1C2326;
    color: #fff;
    top: 0;
}
#right {
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    width:80%;
    background-color:#2D3538;
    color:#fff;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;

}
#footer {
    clear:both;
    height: 80px;
    background-color:#72D27C;
}
```